# Big O Notation and Time Complexity of C++ Code Snippet

Tags: c++, big-o

So I am looking for confirmation of what the time complexity of the c++ code snippet is:

```
for(int i = 0; i<N, i++){
    for(int k = 1; k<N; k*=2){
    //code with O(1)
    }
 }
```

I am thinking this would be `O(NlgN)` where lg is log base 2.
The inner loop would be `O(lgN)` since k is doubling after each iteration. The outer loop is clearly `O(N)`, making the whole code:

```
 O(N)*O(lgN) = O(NlgN).
```

Comment: Exactly the right way to ask the question. The  Suggestion: Stick a counter increment in the inner loop. Run the loop  with N= 100, 200, 400, 800, ... and plot the results. Compare the slope with N* Log(N) to see how good a match it is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is in O(n log n) but the base does not matter in big O notation since `f=n \cdot log_2(n)
\in \mathcal{O}(log_2(n) * n )  \subseteq \mathcal{O}(\frac{ln(n)}{ln(2)} * n )  \subseteq \mathcal{O}(log(n) * n ) \ni f = n \cdot ln (n)` i.e.

[image]

Note the log at the end should still be ln, but people are not caring about the confusion to whenever log is to the base of 10 or e since it does not matter in big O.

So even `for(int k = 2; k<N; k*= k)` would be the same in complexity when using big O notation. However sometimes people are writing down the constant factors when comparing very minor optimisations, but thats not feasible unless you are talking about the [quick sort implementation that runs on billions of instances around the world.](https://kluedo.ub.uni-kl.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/3463/file/wild-master-thesis.pdf)

For the part how we can be sure that your inner loop is in deed bound by `log(n)` I kind of also did not find a nice math proof. Of course executing it is kind of a proof, but my theoretical approach is that, we can agree the inner loop executes as often as your function `k *= 2` needs  a bigger argument to reach `n`, so where `k(x) >= n`, and what do we know which `x` do we need to get the `k(x)` we want, is the inverse function `k^(-1)`, and the inverse functions for `2^x` is `log_2(x)`.